# HTTPBuilder, returning JSON in not the correct format

Tags: json, grails, post, httpbuilder

I have a service that I am built\using  returning data in the below format.

```
def responseData = [
'results': results,
'status': results ? "OK" : "Nothing present"
]

render(responseData as JSON)
```

The output looks like this, I have verified the output according to Fiddler

> {"results":[{"class":"com.companyName.srm.ods.territory.Apo","id":2,"apoId":"5T9B0"}],"status":"OK"}

This is a simple POST call with a body of parameters from a search.

Using HTTPBuilder I get a different result

```
http.request(groovyx.net.http.Method.POST, groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC) {req ->
        uri.path = restUrl
        body = requestData
        response.success = {resp, json ->
            println resp.statusLine.statusCode
            println resp.statusLine
            def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
            String s = json.toString()
            println s
            returnJson = slurper.parseText(s)
        }
        response."422" = {resp, json ->
            println ${resp.statusLine}
        }
        response.failure = {resp ->
            println ${resp.statusLine}
        }
    }
```

> ["results":[{"class":"com.companyName.srm.ods.territory.Apo","id":2,"apoId":"5T9B0"}],"status":"OK":null]

This turns into a Mapped pair where the key is the JSON and the value is null, which is confusing as to why the HTTPBuilder is doing that.

In order to parse to JSON, I have to the following additional coding
    s = s.replace(':null]', '')
    s = s.replace('[', '')

This seems overly complicated for this type of implementation.
I have turned debug and nothing interesting is coming from that.
Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I use builder 0.7.1 and get json response the next way:

```
http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.TEXT) {
            uri.path = pathToService          
            headers.'User' = user
            headers.Accept = 'application/json'
            body  = requestBody  //here I post some json 

            response.success = { resp, reader ->

                //println reader.text;
                println "response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
                return = reader.text
            }

            response.failure = { resp, reader ->
                println "Request failed with status ${resp.status}"
                reader.responseData.results.each {
                println "  ${it.titleNoFormatting} : ${it.visibleUrl}"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just realized the date of question :)  Anyway I hope it will be helpful to other people.